# P4Merge-Equivalent for git

Tags: git, github-api

I am used to work with Perforce and find that their graphical tool [P4Merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools) is very handy, esp. for side-by-side comparison. Is there a similar (graphical) tool for *git*? A Mac solution would be ideal.

I know I can manually set up my `git diff` to launch P4Merge. However, I am looking for something more git specific.

Thanks.

PS: [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) is really good but the file comparison is done not side-by-side.

Comment: The best option I have found on internet and works smoothly with git on most OS X versions on Mac:

```http://pempek.net/articles/2014/04/18/git-p4merge/```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use p4merge, Git has native support for it.  It's the best diff/merge tool I've used for Git ever.  Here's an install guide: https://gist.github.com/1510148

Comment: This is great! Thanks @neu242. Resolving merge conflicts using P4Merge leaves us to choose a resolution between base, local, and remote versions via their GUI. It doesn't give us a flexibility to e.g. add more text into the merged file. Is this observation correct? If yes, do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Your observation is not correct. You can edit the merged text (in the bottom pane) with p4merge.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thanks you! I never knew that we could do that.

Answer (score 4):

If P4merge works for you then

```
git config --global diff.guitool P4merge
```

Personally I use vim with fugitive, but the beauty of git is that you don't need a specific tool.

The gitn family are quite nice ( I use gitg for some complex branch visualisation, git log --graph is nice but a 6 way octopus merge is a scary thing to behold in ascii)

gitx on osx is also pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Richo! But this is exactly what I mentioned in the question for which I am looking an alternative.

Comment: Well, I did mention vim + fugitive, but if you're not a vim user then it may have a steep learning curve. I'm quickly updating my answer with a few other tools.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any built in gui merge tool for git. You have to use third party visual merge tools like tortoisemerge, p4merge, araxis, kdiff3 etc.